# Axios Request Successful but image link in JSON responds with status 403 when trying to display it on a react page

Tags: reactjs, axios

Cannot seem to access the image link received in JSON from the below api call, gives me a status 403 forbidden error.

```
var axios = require('axios').default;
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'someURL', 
            headers: {"someKey":"someValue"},
            data: {"somekey":"someValue"}
            
        };
        axios.request(options).then((response)=>{ 
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({data:response.data.userListDetails})
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.error(error);
        });
```

JSON received back, StudentPhoto is where the link to the image is :-

```
AcademicYear: ""
Board: "`Board Name"
ClassTeacher: ""
CurrentDateTime: "Date"
Division: ""
Last_Login: "Date"
Name: "Name"
OrganizationId: "2"
RoleId: "6"
SchoolId: "40"
SchoolLogo: ""
SchoolName: "School Name"
ShiftName: ""
Standard: ""
StudentEmail: "email"
StudentId: ""
StudentPhoto: ""
StudentUniqueId: ""
UserId: ""
poppup_flag: 0
poppup_imgurl: ""
```

For privacy reasons I could not put in the exact values!

Comment: 403 indicates that you are not allowed to perform the request you're trying to. Are you providing the correct authentication headers?

Comment: @StephanOlsen on further inspection of the link, it seems to be getting an image from a amazon web server. Does the owner of the web server need to whitelist my IP? What I am trying to ask is, it's something from their end and not me doing something wrong?

Comment: If the image is a path directly to an AWS S3 resource and you cannot access it by simply pasting in the url in the browser, then it is on their end. Usually the owner will make the image public, or provide an alternative way to access the image, e.g. through a CDN.

Comment: @StephanOlsen cool, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Code 403 means the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.  Maybe you're using the wrong method, like using POST instead of GET, or you might need to send some authorization with your request.  If your response includes a payload it might state a reason why you're getting a 403.

Can you access the file's URL through your regular browser?  Do you need to be logged in to view the image?  Would it be easier to store the images on your own server?

Comment: Nope cannot access it through my browser either. It seems to be a link to a amazon web server. I guess the owner needs to whitelist my IP?

Comment: No clue, that could be the case or you might need an account on their server or you might just need to send a token in your headers with your request.  It all depends on how their server is written.